Post file from memory stream
I want to upload a picture file without saving it to the hard disk (mainly because of performance). My code is as shown below.
Public Shared Function ConvertToByteArray(ByVal value As Bitmap) As Byte()
        Dim bitmapBytes As Byte()
        Using stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
            value.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            bitmapBytes = stream.ToArray
        End Using
        Return bitmapBytes
    End Function

    Public Sub screenCapture()
        Dim bmp As Bitmap = Screen_Capture() 'api call BitBlt
        Dim data As Byte() = ConvertToByteArray(bmp)

        Dim myWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient()
        myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        Dim responseArray As Byte() = myWebClient.UploadData("https://xxx.php", "Post", data)
        Dim response As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray)
        MsgBox(response)
    End Sub

What am I missing? Thank you in advance for your help.
This code works fine saving it to the hard disk
Public Sub screenCapture()
        Dim bmp As Bitmap = Screen_Capture() 'api call BitBlt

        Dim userName As String = Environment.UserName
        Dim savePath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
        Dim captureSavePath As String = String.Format("{0}\SID\{1}\capture.png", savePath, userName)
        bmp.Save(captureSavePath)
        Dim myWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient()
        Dim responseArray As Byte() = myWebClient.UploadFile("https://xxx.php", "Post", captureSavePath)
        'Dim response As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray)
        'MsgBox(response)
    End Sub


"What am I missing". You're missing an actual problem description. What EXACTLY happens that you don't expect or doesn't happen that you do expect? If there's an exception thrown, what is it and where? If not, what is the specific behaviour at issue?
